# react-select not changing remote url chaining fields

Tags: react-select

I have a two `react-select` Async fields. On one changes second should change url.

```
<AsyncSelect
 name="country"
/>
```

And second field:

```
<AsyncSelect
 name="city"
/>
```

But on change `country` second field loads old `country` cities

Comment: are u change key value?

Comment: @aturan23 Im not using key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change key value to re render second field. 
for example:

```
<AsyncSelect
 name="city"
 key={!!values.country && !!values.country.id ? values.country.id : null}
/>
```

And then ur field be re rendered and get new url